# Get rid of spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb dependency on vulnerable Log4J version

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, log4j, spring-mongodb

Given that Log4J 2.x is suffering from a major remote code execution vulnerability (Check [vulnerability](http://slf4j.org/log4shell.html)), I started taking a look at my project dependencies to see if I use Log4J through e.g. slf4j and luckily I am not.

But I found another dependency on Log4J through `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb`. Last version of the package was produced on [Nov. 2021](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb), so the issue is not mitigated there.

How can I get rid of the dependency without getting rid of `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` as I rely heavily on it.

```
➜  mvn dependency:tree | grep -B 5 log4j
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.12.1:compile
```

Comment: Just define a new version of log4j 2.15.0 in your pom file...furthermore you have only a dependency to log4j-api and not on log4j-core (which is the problem)...and furthermore do you even use log4j 2 in your project?

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for pointing out that this vulnerability is only against the logback-core and not with the log4j-api. Regarding your question, I don't use log4j 2 explicitly but I was not sure if the MongoDB package will use it in a way that I am unaware of given that it has the Log4J as a dependency.

Comment: You are wrong here because the CVE described its against: log4j-core and **NOT** against `logback-core` you should read those things carefully https://www.lunasec.io/docs/blog/log4j-zero-day/ also the link given by @jonrsharpe

Comment: Thanks for correcting me again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [the Spring blog](https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot), you don't need to:

> The `log4j-to-slf4j` and `log4j-api` jars that we include in
> `spring-boot-starter-logging` cannot be exploited on their own. Only
> applications using `log4j-core` and including user input in log
> messages are vulnerable.